# regex expression for `font-size` css parsing

Tags: css, regex

Hi could please tell me what is the proper regex expression for parsing `font-size` css style? I mean that for any of these:

`15px`
`15.23em`
`234.43rem`
`12.342pt`

I would like to get pairs with the value and unit i.e. `(15, px)`, `(15.23, em)` etc.

Comment: What stops you from doing it, how far did you get?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply solve it with 2 regex patterns and parse them into a string literal. To get a chain of connected numbers you can use `/[0-9]+/` where the `+` will not only take the first number but all numbers connected to it. to include a decimal dot you need to use `\.` and can combine them to `/[0-9]+\.[0-9]/`.

To filter for letters you can use `[aA-zZ]` that includes both lowerCase and upperCase letters.

```js
const VALUE = '15.6rem';

console.log(`(${VALUE.match(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)}, ${VALUE.match(/[aA-zZ]+/)})`);
```